# How to format bigint field into a date in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, timestamp, bigint

I have a table with a field of type bigint. This field store a timestamp.
I want to date format the field like this :

```
to_char( bigint_field,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

I get the following error :

```
ERROR: multiple decimal points
État SQL :42601
```

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(bigint_field / 1000), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: @Stephan: either that, or, more probably, what you are storing is a not `UNIX` timestamp. Could you please post a value of `bigint_field` and the date you think it should correspond to?

Comment: [BIGINT] - 1301486917594  roughly equals to 2011-03-30 14:08:37,594

Comment: @Stephan: seems you are storing the number of milliseconds since `1970`. See the post update.

Comment: I am new to postgres. May I know why we need to divide bigint by 1000?

Comment: @AdityaSawant: read the comment thread. `TO_TIMESTAMP(BIGINT)` converts the Unix timestamp (number of seconds since 1970) to a timestamp. The op stores the number of milliseconds in his table.

Answer (score 15):

This is what worked for me

```
to_timestamp( bigint_field/1000)::date
```

Comment: This solution does half the job - by providing the date.  But Stephan clearly wants both the date and time to be output.

Answer (score 6):

This depends on what the bigint value represents - offset of epoch time, or not.

```
select to_timestamp(20120822193532::text, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS')
```

returns

> "2012-08-22 19:35:32+00"

Answer (score 3):

I did it like this:

```
to_timestamp(to_char(20120822193532, '9999-99-99 99:99:99'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

the result looks like this:

> 2012-08-22 19:35:32

you also can use this in you select statemant, just exchange the number with your database colunm.

Step by Step Explanation:

```
to_char(20120822193532, '9999-99-99 99:99:99')
```

This will create a string like this:

> "2012-08-22 19:35:32"

now we can easiely convert this into a timestamp:

```
to_timestamp('2012-08-22 19:35:32','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Result will look the same as before, but it's now a timestamp.

Also, if you use this for a command like

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS SELECT to_timestamp(to_char(tb1.date, '9999-99-99 99:99:99'),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS realDate FROM table1 AS tb1;
```

you might end up with **timstamptz** (timestamp ***with*** time zone) instead of **timestamp** (timestamp ***without*** time zone). You can change it like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table2 ALTER realDate SET DATA TYPE timestamp USING realDate;
```