# Bigint to date in Oracle Error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, bigint

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert Unixtime to Datetime SQL (Oracle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10554405/convert-unixtime-to-datetime-sql-oracle)

We have a table of type bigint. I try to run the following query:

```
select TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(t.bigint_field / 1000), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
   from table t
```

and get this error

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NUMBER
```

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485502/how-can-i-format-bigint-field-into-a-date) but still I am unnable to get rid of this error. Here is one value which I was using - 1340809355000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,
select to_date('1970-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')  +  t.bigint_field/24/60/60/1000    from table t