# postgresql error : Multiple decimal points

Tags: postgresql

So I'm having this query:

```
SELECT 
    TO_CHAR(date_part('hour', created_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'),
    to_char(created_at, 'day') ",
    COUNT(*) AS "
FROM table  
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

When I execute the query I get this:

> ERROR: multiple decimal points

Searching stackoverflow I found some recommendations here:
[How to format bigint field into a date in Postgresql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5485502/how-to-format-bigint-field-into-a-date-in-postgresql) but I don't get why do I have to divide by 1000 and how this would apply in the case of the date_part function.

Comment: what do you try to achieve?.. what is expected result?..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume `created_at` is a timestamp?.. I'm choosing from `date_part(text, timestamp)` and `date_part(text, interval)`, if so `date_part` will return a `double precision`, to which you try to apply the mask `'YYYY-MM-DD HH24'`, eg:

```
v=# select date_part('hour', now());
 date_part
-----------
         9
```

and I don't see how you could possibly get year, month, day and hour from nine...

Yet I assume you wanted to apply the mask against truncated date to the hour precision, which is done with `date_trunc(text, timestamp)`:

```
v=# select date_trunc('hour', now());
       date_trunc
------------------------
 2017-06-20 09:00:00+01
(1 row)
```

so now you can apply the time format:

```
v=# select to_char(date_trunc('hour', now()),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24');
    to_char
---------------
 2017-06-20 09
(1 row)
```

but if this is what you want, then you don't need to truncate time at all:

```
v=# select to_char(now(),'YYYY-MM-DD HH24');
    to_char
---------------
 2017-06-20 09
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I know that the SQL code above seems weird. Actually I'm using a BI tool that uses a markup that afterwards translates this markup into SQL. So this was the "translation". Unfortunately, I can't avoid the mask or the to_char().
Given that, my initial goal is to group some events by the day (Monday, Tuesday etc) and time of the day they occur (1 am, 2 am , 3 am etc). Truncating to hour will keep all the information about month and year which I don't want.  Is there a way to overcome this ?

Comment: Actually I solved my problem using extract. I'm going to accept your answer as it helped very much